# Sabre web services : Delete passenger from PNR

Tags: sabre

I'm trying to delete a passenger from PNR using Sabre web services

What I did is the following

1. 1. Create PNR (1 flight segment 2 passengers)
   2. GetReservation
   3. TravelItineraryModifyInfoRQ (delete passenger)
   4. EndTransaction

EndTransaction shows an error NUMBER OF NAMES NOT EQUAL TO RESERVATIONS

2. 1. Create PNR (1 flight segment 2 passengers)
   2. GetReservation
   3. TravelItineraryModifyInfoRQ (delete passenger)
   4. OTA_CancelRQ (cancel flight)
   5. Book the same flight, but for 1 passenger
   6. EndTransaction

EndTransaction shows an error TO REDUCE NUMBER IN PARTY ENTER COMMA FOLLOWED BY NEW NUMBER

As I understand the error says how to delete passenger using Sabre interact, not web services

Comment: For sample 1, you need to reduce the number of confirmed spaces in the itinerary. For example if you start with 2 passengers, each segment in the itinerary will be HK2. It needs to be HK1 if you are reducing to 1 passenger in the PNR. I'm in middle of researching if there is an API for that, otherwise you can use the host command to send ",1".
I will research a little more and see if there is a better API for that.

In your second example, you need to EndTransaction after step 4, then start a new PNR with 1 passenger.

Comment: @AndyK thanks for your answer, I also found the host command to send using SabreCommand service.

Comment: UpdateReservation API is also contains fields for Passengers and NumberInParty, but it doesn't work for me

Comment: ChangeNbrInParty should work. You need to delete the passenger as you did originally, then <ChangeNbrInParty>
<NewNbrInParty>1</NewNbrInParty>
</ChangeNbrInParty> (Do not send segment), endTransaction. If you get an error, please post and we can try to go from there

Comment: The message I have in this case is
UPDATE RESERVATION PROCESSING ERROR

So it seems I will use host command.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me :

- GetReservation
- TravelItineraryModifyInfoRQ (delete passenger)
- HostCommand ",{new number in party}"
- EndTransaction

Comment: You shouldn't have to use OTA_CancelRQ. You should be able to leave the current segments in with this workflow. Unless you do not want, or are changing, the existing reservation